# Set infinite session timeout but limited per request timeout

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to quickly connect to a couple thousand sites (some up some down), but it seems setting `aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=60)` and passing that in to `ClientSession` means there is only 60 seconds allowable in total for all sites. This means that after about a minute they all quickly fail with `concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError`. I tried raising that timeout, which fixes that failure issue, but then the problem is that all of the threads end up getting hung on non responding sites for the entire length of it.

Is it possible to **disable** the total timeout, however have a per-request timeout of 60 seconds? (Edited) - There **does** seem to be a `timeout` parameter on `session.get(...)`, however it seems that overrides the session timeout and causes the entire session to timeout upon expiration, and not just that request. If I set my `ClientSession` timeout to 600 but the `session.get` timeout to 15, all requests fail after 15 seconds

I want to be able to get through my full list of a couple thousand sites only waiting 60 second max for each connection, but have no total time limit. Is the only way to do this being to create a new session for each request?

```
timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=60)
connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=40)
dummy_jar = aiohttp.DummyCookieJar()
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector, timeout=timeout, cookie_jar=dummy_jar) as session:
     for site in sites:
         task = asyncio.ensure_future(make_request(session, site, connection_pool))
         tasks.append(task)
     await asyncio.wait(tasks)  
connection_pool.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no `timeout` parameter to `session.get`? I am currently unable to check, but the documentation [claims otherwise](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#timeouts).

Comment: Ah right there is, however it seems that overrides the session timeout and causes the entire session to timeout upon expiration, and not just that request. If I set my `ClientSession` timeout to 600 but that `session.get` timeout to 15, all requests fail after 15seconds.

Comment: Ouch, I'd report that as a bug! What you can always do is use `wait_for` to implement a custom timeout. Reliable cancellation is one of the setting points of asyncio, after all (compared to e.g. threads), and this is the perfect use case.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64686124/3339058

Here's a bug where the problem is described in detail: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3203#issuecomment-544136905

The timeout you have set in the example is the per-request timeout. The behaviour you are experiencing is due to the time required to get a connection being included in the "total" time.

The workaround is to use the `sock_*` timeouts with no `total` timeout.